# Proper way of Fragments implementation in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing an app for android lately. I decided to use power of fragments and decided to use dynamic UI. I want to have one fragment included in portrait orientation and two in landscape.

I figured out how to create two layouts and how to add fragments.

Everything is going pretty well until now.

I am trying to find a proper approach to creating and destroying fragments on rotation. I know that I should always check if there is a saved instance, so on rotation there should not be more fragments created. But this solution ignores creating another fragment when user switch from portrait to landscape. So I thought that I need to check orientation before checking if instance was saved. Checking is not the problem but what is the proper way to work with fragments? Should I always create a new fragment and on change rotation remove it? Or have it hidden? 
I found one implementation where is activity that have both fragments and when the rotation is changed the new activity was created. But this solution create activity and fragment for one thing and I am not sure if this is proper approach.

What do you suggest? I think fragments are badly covered by official site for android developers.

Comment: The best app to learn good practices is Google I/O schedule app http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: Your comment was most helpful. Can I somehow vote it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial by Lars Vogel can help you:

[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html)

He creates a landscape application and shows in chapter 11, how to change to portrait mode.

Comment: Yes he is the one that used Activity and Fragment for one thing.